# Create a data structure that has fast insertion, removal, membership testing, and random selection

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

THIS QUESTION WAS NEGATED BECAUSE OF BAD FORMATION. PLEASE RE-READ, I TRIED TO IMPROVE IT.

For the above question, I found following answer:

> "Consider a data structure composed of a hashtable H and an array A.
>   The hashtable keys are the elements in the data structure, and the
>   values are their positions in the array."

`insert(value):`

- Append the value to array `A`
- Let `i` be it's index in A.
- Set `H[value] = i`.

`remove(value): Replace the cell that contains`value`in A with the last element in A.`

- Let `d` be the last element in the array `A`.
- Let `i` be `H[value]`, the index in the array of the value to be removed.
- Set `A[i] = d` and `H[d] = i`
- Decrease the size of the array `A` by one

`contains(value): return true if H contains value`

- Get hash value of `value`
- Use the hash value to index into the bucket that contains `value`
- Return true if `value` can be found at that index

`getRandomElement():`

- `r = random(current size of A).`
- `return A[r]`.

I tried to implement the same in C, could some please help me to answer following doubts with reference to the code

> 1. Should newData be called as a HashTable?
> 2. Is there a way to implement it, without keeping the size in the structure?
> 3. If you were to implement the same what design you would follow?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct data
{
    int A[MAX];
    int size = 0;
}newData;

newData *new;

bool insert(newData *n, int value)
{
    int index;
    index = hash(value)/MAX;
    // assume there is no LL to save extra value
    if ((n->A)[index] == value)
    return false;

    (n->A)[index] = value;
    return true;
}

bool remove(newData *n, int value)
{
    int index;
    index = hash(value) % MAX;
    (n->A)[index] = (n->A)[n->size];
    // is this following a correct way to delete the last element?
    n->size--;
    return true;
}

bool contains(newData *n, value)
{
    int index;
    index = hash(value) % MAX;
    if ((n->A)[index] == value)
        return true;
    return false;
}


int hash(int value)
{
    // assume it calculates a good hash and returns the value
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you never actually remove the elements with the remove function, your randomselection method will return more of that last element in the array than it would any other element

Comment: could you please explain in detail?

Comment: and please stop negating the question, no one even tries to give answer because of it..

Comment: I would guess that people are not responding to the question because it isn't well posed. What is it not doing correctly? What have you done to try to make it work correctly -- have you run it in a debugger or tried adding printouts to see how the variables are changing? Can you narrow the question to something more specific than "please review and rewrite my code"? (The fact that they're down-voting it is probably a result of the same issues, rather than being the cause of reduced responses.) And for the record, I'm _not_ one of those who downvoted it.

Comment: @keshlam, I have improved it please re-read, and let me know if there are any further improvement

Comment: sorry, it something went wrong, again wrote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you are passing your hashtable by value when you should be passing a pointer to it
- Most hashtables resolve collisions by using a linked list to store elements that hash to the same bucket. Then retrieval consists of a linear search of the list to find the element
- Also when you calculate the hash value for your elements, you should divide that number by your bucket size and take the remainder, this shall serve as the new position of the element.
  Unless your hash function is designed to return values in the range `1..100`, you will need to do this to avoid `segmentation fault` errors
- As for removing or deleting elements, if your hashtable uses the linked list collision resolution method, then deleting will simply involve removing the link to that element once your hash function returns the index where the element should be located

Read [this tutorial](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) to understand more about the art of hashing

Comment: A couple of nits: You mean "with a pointer", not "by reference."  There are no references in C.  Open hash tables resolve collisions with lists.  Closed hash tables don't, and they make sense in some applications.  You're right that this isn't one of them. Deletion is rarely simple.

Comment: Ok, could you please recheck?

Comment: Also, please stop negating the question, no bothers to answer it

Comment: @codeymodey, Notice the change I made to the code which was to include the correct way to hash a value to an index `index = hash(value) % MAX;`